# How To Line Up A Header & Sub-Header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up a header and a sub-header; my thought was to use `text-align: justify;` but it's not working. My guess is because the parent is set to `inline-block`?

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9bnqab6n/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">My Business</h1>
        <h3 class="logo">This Is What We Do</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
h3 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.logo {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `h3` text to span across the entire length of the `h1` so they are the same width?

Comment: Do you want them both to be aligned centre or justified so both spread across the same width?

Comment: What do you mean line up? you want them next to each other? Just give .logo { display:inline-block; }

Comment: He means for them to have the same width, not act as inline-blocks, as this will put them on the same line.

Comment: I want them to remain as they are, but always be the same width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `text-align:justify` doesn't work on a single line of text; it's meant for paragraphs. You'll need to style the `.logo:after` like so:

```css
h1, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.logo{
  text-align: justify;
}
.logo:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">My Business</h1>
        <h3 class="logo">This Is What We Do</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should note that this will **double** the height of the heading tags - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/v5jazorz/

Answer (score 0):

In your css file change this:

```
.logo {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

to this:

```
.logo {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't mean to have them on the same line, he means he wants them both to have the same width.